# Got "You need to set the owner in App-only context" while creating Modern Team No Group site collection using OfficeDevPnP package

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using OfficeDevPnP package to create new **Modern Team No Group** site collection but i got below error

> "You need to set the owner in App-only context". See the function
> execution logs for additional details. ---> System.Exception: You need
> to set the owner in App-only context    at
> OfficeDevPnP.Core.Sites.SiteCollection.d__8.MoveNext()

Here is my code,

```
using (ClientContext context = authManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext("TenanatUrl", "ClientId", "ClientSecrete"))
{
    var creationInformation = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.Sites.TeamNoGroupSiteCollectionCreationInformation(siteUrl, siteName, userName);
    var results = await context.CreateSiteAsync(creationInformation);
}
```

I am using **AppOnly** Context here and also provided tenant full control permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions are correct, but in App-only context you need to pass the owner name.

This method, `TeamNoGroupSiteCollectionCreationInformation(siteUrl, siteName, userName)` accepts 3 params the last of which is description. But you need to pass the owner value which is necessary in apponly context, so modify the code as below:

```
var creationInformation = new TeamNoGroupSiteCollectionCreationInformation
{
    Url = siteUrl,
    Title = siteName,
    Owner = userName // login name of a user
};

var results = await context.CreateSiteAsync(creationInformation);
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked..!